# Elastic Beanstalk env.yaml contains invalid key

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have recently updated my EB environment to php 8.0 and in my env.yaml I now have

```
AWSConfigurationTemplateVersion: 1.1.0.0
SolutionStack: 64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.3.1 running PHP 8.0
```

However I am getting this warning when I run `eb deploy`

```
WARN    Error processing file (Skipping): 'env.yaml' - Contains invalid key: 'SolutionStack'. For information about valid keys, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html
```

I am using the solution stack from the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platforms-supported.html#platforms-supported.PHP)

I have also tried using the Platform key instead but get the same result

```
AWSConfigurationTemplateVersion: 1.1.0.0
Platform:
  PlatformArn: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-east-1::platform/PHP 8.0 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.3.1
```

Has anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i can confirm seeing this warning in AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I got the following message when performing a platform upgrade by replacing instances:

```
Error processing file (Skipping): 'env.yaml' - Contains invalid key: 'SolutionStack'. For information about valid keys, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html
```

But the upgrade went on without problems and the app is running fine.

My `env.yaml` starts as follows:

```
AWSConfigurationTemplateVersion: 1.1.0.0
SolutionStack: "64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.4.13 running Docker"
```

According to this documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-cfg-manifest.html `SolutionStack` is a valid key.